# Site to Site Migration in SharePoint Online (Versioning Needed)

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, migration

I am trying to capture files from a "island" site that my company created when we were first learning sharepoint to our now more permanent infrastructure. The problem I am having is finding some way to migrate these documents and still retaining their version control. We need to maintain the versioning to stay compliant with our policies, but every method I have tried in migrating these documents, the final product is a copied document with a new version.

Any thoughts?

Please note, I am on SharePoint online 365 so they have done a pretty efficient job taking out all cross navigation from the SharePoint features.

Comment: A free 15 day trial of ShareGate?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use content and structure to move the content and maintain versions.

Comment: does that apply to SharePoint online? and If it does where can I find that because I have not been able to find content/structure on SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no out of the box feature in SharePoint online to do what you are asking for.

3rd party tools are filling that gap for now.